Was there a version of "Law and Oracle" where Schrödinger's cat is dead?
I was certain there was a version of the Futurama episode where Schrödinger's cat was dead

In a word, no. There was at least one deleted scene that was written and storyboarded, but it was from earlier in the episode and had nothing to do with the cat-in-a-box gag.
Obviously in a multiverse anything is possible, but we're in the universe where that scene doesn't exist.

Someone opened the door of the writing room at the wrong time and the scene died.
